# Same PHP script in different pages changes characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpactiverecord

I am using php activerecord, and in two different sections of an application I get a photo asset from a database like so:

```
$p = Photo::find(12891);
//I insert its caption to a log file for debugging purposes
file_put_contents('log.txt',$p->caption);
```

In one log file inspected in a text editor, the file will read "over 60  days" (notice two spaces in between 60 and days)

In another log, the file will read "over 60 †days" with that cross character replacing the second space

So something seems to be messing with the character encoding, but I don't know how or why, the PHP configurations are the exactly same where both scripts are running, they are using the exact same function etc

** the log files are not the issue, basically the problem is if you pull the photo object from the database in one script and re-save it,even without modification, the content changes. If you do it in the other, it's fine. the log files were just to illuminate the issue

Comment: Did you checked your file encoding?

Comment: Both the log files were generated from php file_put_contents, and one had encoding at UTF-8 and one has encoding set to unknown. And really the log files are not the issue, the issue is what's happening downstream because of this character issue, was just trying to illuminate it with log files

Comment: So you log into two files with different encoding and are surprised if there were "different" things logged?

Comment: Alright saw your edit now. But what is the file encoding of the two script-files?

Comment: php generated both files with the same configuration...why did it choose to make them different encodings? something was amiss before the log files were generated

Comment: two scripts are both charset=us-ascii